# Touchpad acting weird in 14.04 on MSI CR70 2M

Tags: xorg, touchpad, xinput, msi, elantech

I don't know if I am doing it right(or at the right place). It's the first time I report a bug.

I have a disturbing bug. My touchpad left click (tapping and mechanical) stops working sometimes. It seems to be linked to click and drag and/or right click. Login out and back in solve the problem. I have control of the left click again (although mechanical click sometime don't work back).

My laptop is a MSI CR70 2M - french keyboard. The touchpad is detected as an Elantech touchpad.

I have already try some solution but nothing is working.
I have some log file: evtest- xev - xinput - xmodmap - Xorg.log (I have followed https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection)

I don't know where to publish the log file. Can someone guide me?

Thank you a lot for the job done for Ubuntu.

Regards,

Yodhur

Comment: go to http://paste.ubuntu.com and put it in there. Then post the link here, in a comment or by [edit]ing your answer.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up. So here are the log files. Hope this can help.
Thank you.

evtest : http://paste.ubuntu.com/7980447/
xev : http://paste.ubuntu.com/7980457/
xinput : http://paste.ubuntu.com/7980463/
xmodmap : http://paste.ubuntu.com/7980465/
Xorg.log : http://paste.ubuntu.com/7980467/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For now the problem has been solved and the patch has been pushed to the mainstream.** You can subscribe to the `xorg-edgers` ppa to get the latest updates and thus the immediate solution. Here are the commands if you want to add it:

```sh
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

**[QUICK SOLUTION]** If you can't wait for official release, I've quickly applied [this patch](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=86288) against `xorg-xserver-1.16.1` 64bit version, and it has solved the problem. If you have another architecture please follow [these steps](https://bugs.launchpad.net/xorg-server/+bug/1220426/comments/201), otherwise execute the steps below:

1. Download the archive [here](https://www.sendspace.com/file/q5o3ul).
2. Run these commands in the terminal:

   ```sh
   cd Downloads 
   tar -xvf Patched\ XServer\ 1.16.1.tar.gz
   cd Patched\ XServer
   sudo dpkg -i xdmx_1.16.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb xdmx-tools_1.16.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb xnest_1.16.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb xorg-server-source_1.16.0-1ubuntu1_all.deb xserver-common_1.16.0-1ubuntu1_all.deb xserver-xephyr_1.16.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb xserver-xorg-core_1.16.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb xserver-xorg-core-dbg_1.16.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb xserver-xorg-dev_1.16.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb xserver-xorg-xmir_1.16.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb xvfb_1.16.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb xwayland_1.16.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
   ```

**[IMPORTANT]:** *This solution will be pushed officially in the PPA in the upcoming release, so if you have read this post long after its publishing date, please just update xorg as mentioned before and it'll solve your problem.*

Comment: Everything seems to work back.
Thank you for the support.