# Ubuntu 14.10 screen freeze randomly

Tags: freeze, 14.10

The Ubuntu is installed to Dell Vostro 3460 with nVidia GT630M graphhics card.

Screen freeze randomly when using touch pad, and to fast "unfreeze" the screen I've to switch to console terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) and back to graphical console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>)

I found this solution:

1.) Run following command from terminal:

```
echo "options psmouse proto=imps" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/psmouse.conf >/dev/null
```

2.) Reboot the system or reload psmouse module from terminal with following commands:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse && sudo modprobe psmouse
```

3.) Increase the speed of pointer under System settings > Mouse & Touchpad

Really solve this, but it does not work the touchpad scrolling.

My Xorg.0.log:

```
[ 1921.662] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "NULL"
[ 1921.780] (II) intel(G0): switch to mode 1366x768@60.0 on LVDS1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
[ 1921.814] (--) synaptics: AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint: touchpad found
[ 1921.922] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-52D12E52E86EC353998055F673024E8168C40E99.xkm
[ 1921.938] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-52D12E52E86EC353998055F673024E8168C40E99.xkm
[ 1921.947] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-52D12E52E86EC353998055F673024E8168C40E99.xkm
[ 1921.972] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-52D12E52E86EC353998055F673024E8168C40E99.xkm
[ 1921.996] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-52D12E52E86EC353998055F673024E8168C40E99.xkm
[ 1922.018] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-52D12E52E86EC353998055F673024E8168C40E99.xkm
[ 1922.029] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-52D12E52E86EC353998055F673024E8168C40E99.xkm
[ 1922.059] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-52D12E52E86EC353998055F673024E8168C40E99.xkm
[ 2193.983] reporting 4 5 8 61
```

Comment: This bug has been solved, and the solution will be released very soon. If you can't wait until then, you can execute [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/550603/349383) quick solution.